# Windows Task Scheduler not running task on event

Tags: windows-10, scheduled-tasks, event-log, event-viewer

I'm trying to run a task when I get a network connection and am following [these](https://www.groovypost.com/howto/automatically-run-script-on-internet-connect-network-connection-drop/) steps.

I created a test.bat that does some stuff script that and set the task scheduler trigger for it to Log: Microsoft-Windows-NetworkProfile/Operational
Source: NetworkProfile
Event ID: 10001

(just on disconnect for now).

When I disconnect from my wifi, in the Event Viewer I can see under Event Viewer->Application and Services Logs->Microsoft->->Windows->NetworkProfile->Operational that the event with ID 10001 is created. However, my bat script is never run.
When I run the task manually or schedule it at a certain time, everything works just fine.

Comment: Does the task's *Last Run Time* indicate that it attempted to run when the event is logged? If so, what's the *Last Run Result*? Anything on the *History* tab of the task? Also, review the `Microsoft/Windows/Task Scheduler` event log for any relevant events.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found the solution: 
For some reason, the trigger was set as

> Log:Microsoft-Windows-NetworkProfile/Operational, Source:NetworkProfile, Event ID: 10001

When I created a new task (I'm so sure I followed the same steps to a T!), the trigger was listed as

> Log:Microsoft-Windows-NetworkProfile/Operational, Source:Microsoft-Windows-NetworkProfile, Event ID: 10001

which worked. (No idea what I did wrong the first time).

Comment: On my machine the "NetworkProfile" was suggested by Windows itself, but to get it to work you have to use "Microsoft-Windows-NetworkProfile", as you said. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I had an event driven task which would not fire upon the event occurring because there is a task "conditions" setting to `Start the task only if the computer is on AC power`.

I was running a test on my laptop without being plugged in.  Thus, the condition was not met!  Check all these conditions compared to your exact scenario if you encounter a similar problem.